# Postgresql tutorial files

Tags: linux-mint, postgresql

Similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136670/where-can-i-find-tutorial-files-of-postgresql

However I am trying to find the folder src/tutorial, to start the SQL tutorial, or even understand if I downloaded the right distro.

Using `apt list --installed` shows I have the following packages:

```
postgresql-10
postgresql-client-10
postgresql-client-common
postgresql-common
postgresql-server-dev-10
```

As well when I used the command: `sudo find . -type d -name "tutorial` it doesn't return any folder "tutorial" sub directoried in "src". (I ran this command from root dir)

Can anyone help with some pointers on where to get the tutorial started?

Try here for extra packages: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Compile_and_Install_from_source_code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Debian "Buster" installation, the tutorials are included in the `postgresql-doc` package.

```
 sudo apt-get install postgresql-doc
```

The tutorials are installed into the following directory:

```
/usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-10/tutorial
```

I'm running postgresql-10, so the documentation matches the installed version.

Since *Mint* is Debian based, it's likely the package and file locations are the same.  Here is the package information from 'apt-cache':

```
$ apt-cache show postgresql-doc

Package: postgresql-doc
Source: postgresql-common (190)
Version: 10+190
Installed-Size: 62
Maintainer: Debian PostgreSQL Maintainers <pkg-postgresql-public@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Depends: postgresql-doc-10
Description-en: documentation for the PostgreSQL database management system
 This metapackage always depends on the currently supported PostgreSQL database documentation package.
.
 PostgreSQL is a fully featured object-relational database management
 system.  It supports a large part of the SQL standard and is designed
 to be extensible by users in many aspects.  Some of the features are:
 ACID transactions, foreign keys, views, sequences, subqueries,
 triggers, user-defined types and functions, outer joins, multiversion
 concurrency control.  Graphical user interfaces and bindings for many
 programming languages are available as well.
```

***Please note:***

You may need to install the `build-essential` package in order to compile the tutorial programs.

Comment: Great! This got me the tutorial folder with Makefile... however when I tried: $ sudo make it returned a fatal error: stdio.h: no such file or directory. Is this something I should submit a bug for on their github?

Comment: @GregIven ... make sure you've installed the `build-essential` package.

Comment: Doh! Had to get the build-essential package plus a few more. I added the help doc to the original post.